# Adding/Removing a user to private O365 group using SPFx

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, spfx

Unable to add/remove members to the **O365 private group** with Group.ReadWrite.All and User.Read.All permission using MSGraphClient in SharePoint Framework(SPFx) webpart.

I have approved the permissions from SharePoint Admin API Access page, so that my "SharePoint Online Client Extensibility Web Application Principal" get the required delegated permissions. Even tried with GroupMember.ReadWrite.All and Directory.ReadWrite.All permissions.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{groupid}/members/$ref
{
    "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userid}"
}
```

also tried with below body

```
{
    "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/{userid}"
}
```

Below is the error text:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error making HttpClient request in queryable [403] Forbidden ::> {
  "error": {
    "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
    "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-09-09T20:18:44",
      "request-id": "ea951e6c-ae43-4907-8c86-e6f6c8346462"
    }
  }
}
```

When I sign in using O365 account other than Group owners account, I get this error. It works fine when I use the Group Owner account to run the same code.

Here are the screenshots from both API management and Azure AD App pages
[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks like the permissions didn't take effect. Can you provide a screenshot of the delegated permissions configured in Azure AD app?

Comment: Updated the post with screenshots

Comment: Parse the access token in https://jwt.io to check if it includes the required permissions.

Comment: Yes, It shows the required permission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is by design. Even though the Azure AD application has the required delegated permissions, if the user is not an admin or the owner of the private group, he will not be allowed to add members into it.

Same behavior is in O365 portal.

When a general user try to add members to a private group, it will show "
You can only add members to groups you have access to." and fail to add members.

If you assign an admin role (user admin or group admin) to the user, he can add members successfully. And if you add the user (without admin role) as the owner of the group, he can add members as well.

Answer (score 0):

Following are the permissions applied:

1. [Delegated permissions in Azure AD App Registration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YldI2.png)
2. [Approved Permissions in SharePoint Admin API Access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeqjx.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your spfx has been granted permission in admin-center.
[image]

Comment: Yes, We have approved the permissions in the mentioned screen (SharePoint Admin center - API Management page)

Comment: It's strange.Same issue in graph explorer.

Comment: Yes, We have seen the same issue from Graph Explorer